# Problems in Integrating Laravel Templates from Creative Tim

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel, and I'm trying to integrate paper dashboard from creative tim for my laravel project, I followed installation instructions from this link - https://github.com/laravel-frontend-presets/paper-dashboard

I installed it via composer but it shows this problem...
[istallation via composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BmtP.jpg)

I also tried installing the paper-dashboard by using the archive instruction and this problem shows... 
[installation by using archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68kWK.jpg)

this is my *PaperPresetServiceProvider.php* file
[PaperPresetServiceProvider.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMOZM.jpg)

can someone please help me know what is missing or what am I going to do to successfully integrate paper-dashboard in my laravel project? big thanks...

I'm using 
(Laravel Framework 7.0.6)
(Composer version 1.9.3)
(PHP 7.4.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some themes isn't supported on Laravel 7 yet I think.
I suggest making it at version 6.x.
 You can make a specific version of laravel project by putting a version at the end.

Example:
 **composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 6.***

6.* means latest laravel 6.x

Comment: i did create new project with laravel v6.18.0 (the latest version 6 of laravel) and tried to integrate the paper dashboard and Voilà, the the laravel template works. Thanks sigel. probably gonna use v6 from now.